# How to read files one by one from ftp server using c#?

Tags: c#, ftp

I am getting files from ftp folder like this.

```
request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://ipaddress/foldername"));
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                request.UseBinary = true;

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        result.Append(line);
                        result.Append("\n");
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    // to remove the trailing '\n'
                    result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
                    reader.Close();
                    response.Close();

                    string[] results = result.ToString().Split('\n');

                    foreach (string filename in results)

                    {
 connetionString = "Data Source=testservername;Initial Catalog=testdb;User ID=sa;Password=sa";
                   connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);


                   FtpWebRequest request1 = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://servername/"  + filename));
                   request1.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                   request1.UseBinary = true;
                   request1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                   responses = (FtpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();
                   StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(responses.GetResponseStream());

                   string xml = reader1.ReadToEnd();



                   ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)));

                   int i = 0;
                   connection.Open();
                   for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1 ; i++)
                    {

                   sql = "insert into Details values('" + ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ItemArray[0]            
                                                       + "')";

                        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                        adpter.InsertCommand = command;
                        adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }


                        FtpWebRequest requestDelete = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://sername/" + filename);
                        requestDelete.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                        requestDelete.UseBinary = true;
                        requestDelete.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                        responseDelete = (FtpWebResponse)requestDelete.GetResponse();
                        try
                        {
                            string res = responseDelete.StatusDescription;
                            if (res == "250 Delete operation successful.")
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Done......");

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                        }
                    }

                    responseDelete.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                    responses.Close();



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
```

Hi need to get files from ftp folder and read that xml files one by one and save it as records in my Databse after that need to delete that file ftp folder.

if for testing i placed two files in ftp folder first files reading successfully .but getting error for reading second file like "Object Reference is not set instance of object "in the below line.

```
ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)));
```

please tell me any thing wrong in my code.i am sending ftp request multiple times it is good or suggest me by seeing above lines of code how to do that?